# Jquery Clone of draggable div

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, clone

You can see my jsfiddle for reference to the below question:

I am trying to make my draggable divs clone but I am having an issue.  I want to drag from the group below "Drag From The Below Tiles!" and drop them into the tiles above.  However, instead of the original staying in the box, it is moving to on top of the dropped element.  How do I make the original draggable remain in the lower set of boxes.

And I only want the draggable class "Component" to be droppable in the divs with a class of "GridDiv".

jsfiddle.net/humphrey_brent/0zcLp0La/69/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*helper* property should be usefull

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper